# Node.js crypto Signer won't generate signature

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I have the following code:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var signer = crypto.createSign("sha1");
signer.update("abc123");
var key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"sign.key"),"utf8");
var sig = signer.sign(key,"hex");
```

I have tried with "sha1", "sha", "sha256" (Which is the one I want), and "RSA-SHA256".
No matter what I do, the "signer.sign" call always returns an empty string.

I have also tried all of these on 2 separate machines (OSX and Linux)

The private key is in the form:
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
And I know it is correct since I have successfully tested in with another system

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the answer so I'm going to answer myself here in case anyone is looking it.

It seems the **certificate** file **MUST** be **saved** as **ASCII**.

Even if you specify ascii as the encoding, it will still not work.

I'm not sure exactly why this is, as I would expect V8 to normalize all strings into the same encoding (UTF-8?), but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
var key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"sign.key"),"binary");
```

Hope it works.